# CSS issue on page that contain same tag element

Tags: jquery, html, css

CSS issue on page that contain same tag element

I have a page that is build by wordpress engine.
Problem is this style.css which my default css for the page contains CSS element for tag

```
<ul> and <li>
```

I am trying to use an external jquery tabbed menu which also make use of the same tags, I create the tabbed menu at a new page, the jquery tab menu look & feel works fine.

But when I integrate it into my own page, it become overwrite and use the default style.css

How do I overcome this issue so it will use the css of the correct stylesheet.

Thanks for helping

My tab menu look something like this

I added this on the **header code**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
</head>
```

**Body code**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB MENU 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB MENU 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">TAB MENU 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">

</div>
<div id="tabs-2">

</div>
<div id="tabs-3">

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping.. I added a class="maintabs" to my ul but it seems that it still display like the rest of the ul tag.

My site that I am testing on is this site

```
http://www.epdrama.com/tab-menu/
```

the code is at the bottom of the page

```
Korean Drama
Korean Variety
Japan Drama
```

I not sure why the original tag will conflcit, despite I try assign a class to the ul

and the page that works fine is this page

```
http://www.epdrama.com/11.php
```

Comment: can you not add an id to the ul and target that with the new styles?

Comment: @Pete Sorry for the confusion, actually my problem with this is if I do the tab menu code independently at epdrama.com/11.php, its work fine, but when I integrate the same code into http://www.epdrama.com/tab-menu/ , the display of the code is totally different, it does not display in tab menu version, I wonder what conflict the code, I think its probably something to do with the css since the look & feel is affected. Sorry for the inconveniences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this order

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
</head>
```

for more detail read [this](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/css-file-include-order)

Comment: I changed the order but the page http://www.epdrama.com/tab-menu/ still does not display the same as epdrama.com/11.php

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.epdrama.com/resources/demos/style.css". i think file is not on the right path.

Comment: The file doesn't affect the look and feel of the tab menu, because I check it just contain a body code.

Comment: i saw in firebug there is issue with jquery .live() function. you are using jquery-1.10.2.js where .live function doesn't exists. replace .live() function with .on()

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement classes to spearate them from eachother.

Like ul.this-list-style and ul.that-list-style and so on :)

Comment: Thanks for replying, where should I implement the class at, at the div or at the ul and li only . Thanks!

Comment: On the ul. Like <ul class="this-list-class" or something. I see now that you updated your post, then you can make like this:

    [id^="tabs"] { color: pink; //or whatever }

Comment: I tried to add a maintabs to the css but it still appear to use the original ul, hence make the tab menu not working . I added my site with 1 working and 1 not working version

Answer (score 0):

Use classes and IDs to differentiate between them

See [w3schools>](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

**EDIT due to updated question**

Try something along the lines of:

```
#tabs > ul{
 /* CSS style for ul children of tabs
}
#tabs-1 > ul{
 /* CSS style for ul children of #tabs-1
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but it seems it still take the css from the original page

Comment: Are you sure your CSS file is correctly linked? If so, try adding !important; to the end of the style declaration, I.e. font-size:1em !important;

Comment: I tried to add a maintabs to the css but it still appear to use the original ul, hence make the tab menu not working . I added my site with 1 working and 1 not working version

Comment: We are not getting the full picture here I think.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, actually my problem with this is if I do the tab menu code independently at http://www.epdrama.com/11.php, its work fine, but when I integrate the same code into http://www.epdrama.com/tab-menu/ , the display of the code is totally different, it does not display in tab menu version, I wonder what conflict the code, I think its probably something to do with the css since the look & feel is affected. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the CSS file that styles your menu and just put this before each of the menu styles:

```
#tabs
```

So, for example:

```
#tabs ul {
}
```

Or:

```
#tabs ul li {
}
```

That way those styles only affect the elements in your `#tabs` div.  Also, since those styles are now more explicit than the generic `ul` and `li` styles in your other CSS file, they will take precedence.

Comment: Hihi, is the problem with my div or ul, do i need add class for li tag also ? Thanks for helping